# Can an View play its animation out of its parent?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-animation

I have some `ImageView`s in a `TableLayout`'s `TableRow`. When I start an animation of one `ImageView` using the following code:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(id);
TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 80);             
a.setDuration(500);
image.startAnimation(a);
```

the image is expected to move downwards. But unfortunately it's in a `TableRow`, so I can see the image moves "in the backstage of the row". Any ideas? I can't use other layouts because of a lot of existing codes.

Comment: I investigated this for a few hours about a year ago and at least then the answer was: No. Either "copy" the view and place it in another view that covers the entire animation-surface, and then play it (which is a huge fuzz), or make your own TableLayout (which is also a huge fuzz). But back then I assumed 1.5 compatibility, there might be a solution for newer versions of android out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Animations change properties of an view, but can't take it out of its parent. At last I gave up and use another layout.